# Tense or Mood? - "Das muss schwer für dich gewesen sein"

Tags: modal-verb, tense, grammatical-mood

I recently learned the phrase *Das muss schwer für dich gewesen sein* ("That must have been hard for you"). Could you tell me, is this a part of the subjunctive? Where could I find charts which show how to form this? Is it the subjunctive? I have never learned  a construction like this.

Answer (score 7):

The finite verb is *muss*, which is 3rd person singular present indicative. Like all modal verbs, it combines with a bare infinitive, *sein*, which in this example combines with a past participle *gewesen* to form the infinitive perfect of *sein*, *gewesen sein*.

So no subjunctive in sight. But it is worth pointing out that the modal verb is used epistemically ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistemic_modality)) here, i.e. it is used to indicate the speaker's degree of certainty in the truth of the proposition *das ist schwer für dich gewesen*. In this case, *muss* indicates a high degree of certainty and could be paraphrased as *I'm sure*.

Two further examples with *muss* plus infinitive perfect. Note how the choice of auxiliary depends on the participle: *täuschen* forms its perfect with *haben*, therefore the infinitive perfect is *getäuscht haben*; *sein* forms its perfect with *sein*, therefore the infinitive perfect is *gewesen sein*.

> Martin Schulz hat mal gesagt, Wolfgang Sevenich habe ihn mit der Fußballmannschaft der D-Jugend bei Rhenania abgelichtet. „Aber ich finde nichts“, sagt der Fotograf. Und wenn Wolfgang Sevenich in seinem Archiv nichts findet, kann das nur eines heißen: Der SPD-Kanzlerkandidat **muss** sich **getäuscht haben**. ([1](https://www.aachener-zeitung.de/lokales/nordkreis/alte-bilder-von-martin-schulz-er-hat-sie_aid-24665635))
>
> … *must have been wrong (about having his picture taken by Sevenich)*
>   "Es ist ziemlich sicher, dass Schulz sich **getäuscht hat**."

> Wer den DRK Ortsverein in Hasbergen besucht, läuft definitiv dem Ehepaar Brönstrup über den Weg. Die zwei sind seit Jahrzehnten aktive Mitglieder und haben "bis auf die Sozialarbeit alles durch", meint Adrian Schäfer, zweiter Vorsitzender des Ortsvereins über Manfred Brönstrup. Seine Frau Helga ist durch ihren Mann dazugekommen. "Etwa 1985 **muss** das **gewesen sein**", erklärt sie. ([2](https://www.noz.de/lokales/hasbergen/artikel/1850438/selbstloser-einsatz-fuers-drk-hasbergen-1))
>
> *That must have been around 1985.*
>   "Es ist ziemlich sicher, dass das etwa 1985 **gewesen ist**."

Finally, two examples with an infinitive instead of an infinitive perfect. I've selected cases with reported speech introduced by *vermutet*, which indicates that the epistemic reading – being fairly certain – is correct.

> [Das Mädchen] lässt ihr Buch und ihren grünen Schal neben sich auf den Boden fallen und sucht den Blick von Lyn Bentschik. Diese reagiert sofort. Es scheint, als würden sich all ihre Gesichtszüge für einen Moment erweichen und sie lächelt. Ein Lächeln über das ganze Gesicht. „Es war schön zu sehen, wie dieser Moment der Vertrautheit entstanden ist“, bemerkt auch Besucherin Ulrike Becks-Malorny und **vermutet**: „Die beiden **müssen** sich **kennen**, das hat man irgendwie gespürt.“ ([3](http://www.general-anzeiger-bonn.de/news/kultur-und-medien/bonn/Zahlreiche-Besucher-bestaunen-Performance-in-Bundeskunsthalle-article3880716.html))
>
> *These two must know each other.*
>   "Es ist ziemlich sicher, dass die beiden sich **kennen**."

> „Der Druck auf Sellström, sich zur Schuldfrage im Sinne der großen Mächte zu äußern – oder gar nicht –, **muss** enorm **sein**“, **vermutet** deshalb Oliver Meier. ([4](https://www.tagesspiegel.de/politik/suchen-und-schweigen/8660546.html))
>
> *The pressure … must be enormous.*
>   "Es ist ziemlich sicher, dass der Druck enorm **ist**."

If you compare the paraphrases introduced by *es ist ziemlich sicher, dass …* with the examples with *müssen* you will see that the latter simply have an infinitive instead of a finite verb.

> **ist** enorm → muss enorm **sein**
>   **ist** 1985 gewesen → muss 1985 gewesen **sein**
>   **hat** sich getäuscht → muss sich getäuscht **haben**

Comment: +1 for mentioning the epistemic dimenision. I would add that _muss_ also indicates a momentum of reflexion, or empathy, as in _I can imagine, this has been hard for you._ This stems, I would say, from the fact that the degree of certainty of the speaker is made thematic at all.

Comment: Good point! It seems by bringing the degree of certainty into play at all, the speaker communicates being open to discussion. As opposed to: *Ja, das war schwer für dich, aber …* where the speaker wants to move on.

Comment: So muss + sein is the indicative. So what is 'gewesen'. Yes, its the past participle of 'sein' but I'm trying to learn from the whole construction and make some of my own examples. So, in some sense I'm trying to figure a formula of what is going on here, if that make sense?

Comment: *Das muss schwer für dich sein.* is *Präsens* while *Das muss schwer für dich gewesen sein.* is *Perfekt*. This is a bit obscure here because *sein* builds its *Perfekt* with *sein*. So the *sein* from the *Präsens* example becomes *gewesen* and takes an addtional *sein* as an auxiliary in the *Perfekt* example.

Comment: @janka Isn't *muss* the main verb in the sentence? In that sense, the sentence is set in the present time, as you could also say »**Es muss sein** (=ist sicher), dass es für dich schwer gewesen ist.« (and not »Es musste sein...« or »Es hat sein gemusst...«).

Comment: The modals are special as they introduce a second time in which the modal condition takes place. *Er muss es gewesen sein.* ≠ *Er hat es sein müssen.* The latter is very obscure, at least for *müssen*. Let's use an example with *wollen*: *Er will es gewesen sein.* ≠ *Er hat es sein wollen.* The first has the declaration of the wish in the present, while the second has that declaration in the past. The action is in the past in both examples.

Comment: @DavidVogt Yes, this is an example of Grice's theory of the cooperative principle, I'd say. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle